# calculate bounding box after rotation

Tags: numpy, image-processing

I have an image and the corresponding bounding box of 4 points it looks like this `[685,601,832,743]` , i want to perform some rotations like 90, 180, 270 etc.

I am not sure how to get the bounding box of the image lets say after i rotate the image 90.I am using imagemagick to perform the rotation,i looked for any function that would give me the bounding box after i rotate the image, but i was not able to find any, i have been stuck on this for 3+ hours.Any suggestions at this point would be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your statement is confusing. You say 4 points, but points are x,y values. So you would need 8 values and you only show 4.  Do your values simply correspond to the top-left x,y and bottom-right x,y? Are you asking for the new corner coordinates or the rectangular bounding box of the new image? Please clarify or show a diagram. If you want the corner coordinates, then look up coordinate rotation on Google. A bounding box of those coordinates is then easy to compute from the max and min values. In ImageMagick, you do not need to compute the new bounding box. It will be that size automatically

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes for coordinate rotation computations or https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223522781

Answer (score 0):

Using ImageMagick and some bash shell scripting, here is how to compute it.

The basic point rotation equations are used. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes). However, since rotation is about the center, one must subtract the center coordinates of the input from the point coordinates, do the rotation and then add the center of the output image back.

Note that ImageMagick rotations are clockwise, while the usual coordinate transformation equations are specified for counterclockwise. So I have to negate the rotation angle.

Also note that Y is positive downward in image coordinates and the normal coordinate rotation has Y upwards. So there is a swap of signs in the equations between image and a normal Cartesian coordinate system.

Here is a test image that I create:

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:skyblue -size 100x100 xc:pink -geometry +50+50 -composite test.png
```

[image]

So obviously (from the ImageMagick command), the 4 corners are:

```
pt1=50,50
pt2=149,50
pt3=149,149
pt4=59,149
```

The bigger values (149) are 1 less than the pink dimensions plus the start coordinates (100-1+50=149), since indexing starts at 0 in ImageMagick. Offsets are relative to 0.

Next I rotate the image:

```
convert test.png -background black -rotate 20 test2.png
```

[image]

So to compute the 4 points in the output, I first need to know how big the output will be for the given rotation angle.

```
angle=20
ww=300
hh=300
ang=-$angle
wwr=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:($ww*cos(pi*abs($ang)/180)+$hh*sin(pi*abs($ang)/180))]" info:)
hhr=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:($ww*sin(pi*abs($ang)/180)+$hh*cos(pi*abs($ang)/180))]" info:)
echo "$wwr x $hhr"
384.514 x 384.514

Rounding to whole numbers, it would be
wwr=385
hhr=385

Note for computing the new dimensions, I use the abs of the sin and cos and all positive signs
```

Next, I reformat the 4 points into X and Y arrays for processing later.

```
pt1=50,50
pt2=149,50
pt3=149,149
pt4=59,149
list="$pt1 $pt2 $pt3 $pt4"
echo "$list"
i=0
for pt in $list; do
xArr[$i]=$(echo "$pt" | cut -d, -f1)
yArr[$i]=$(echo "$pt" | cut -d, -f2)
i=$((i+1))
done
echo "${xArr[*]}"
50 149 149 59
echo "${yArr[*]}"
50 50 149 149
```

Now, I compute the rotated 4 corner coordinates:

```
angle=20
xlast=299
ylast=299
wwr=385
hhr=385
for ((i=0; i<4; i++)); do
xr=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:((${xArr[$i]}-300/2)*cos(pi*$ang/180)+(${yArr[$i]}-300/2)*sin(pi*$ang/180)) + $wwr/2]" info:)
yr=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:((${yArr[$i]}-300/2)*cos(pi*$ang/180)-(${xArr[$i]}-300/2)*sin(pi*$ang/180)) + $hhr/2]" info:)
echo "$xr,$yr"
done
132.733,64.3287
225.762,98.1887
191.902,191.218
107.33,160.436
```

You can measure them in the output image to see that they are correct. You can round to whole numbers as desired.

If you want the rectangular bounding box, then just compute the minx, miny, maxx, maxy values.